# How to exclude extra jar files from shar-amp.amp

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco sdk 2.1 I have obeserved during build it is packaging many **jar files within Share AMP file**. I want to get rid of all those files and keep it light weight.Is there any way to do it apart from manually removing those jars files from AMP? I was also wondering weather it will break something in some scenerios because till now I did not come across any such scenerios.

Comment: Do you mean you have in your AMP a lot of dependecies that already exist in the share deployed application?

Comment: Yes few of them are already exist in share war file like "Apache Commons Jars" and few of them are not useful in alfresco like selenium related jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resulting AMPs contains too many JARs please make sure that you

- Do a `mvn clean install` when building your artifacts for deployment
- Inspect the dependencies in `pom.xml` and make sure to set `<scope>provided</scope>` for the ones you don't need

Which JARs end up in the AMP? Any dependencies you specified yourself or?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ole for your response.

I was able to get rid of those jars by adding `<scope>provided</scope>` in following dependency config in pom.xml of share

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0-alfresco</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: To follow up, the issue you encountered was this: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/300 which is fixed for the upcoming 2.1.1 release. By default if you add a dependency without specifying a scope it will be included in the AMP. If you don't need the dependency, or know that it is provided by Alfresco (inside the alfresco/share.war) you specify provided as well.